# Error: Missing Dependency: /usr/X11R6/bin/xmessage is needed by package wine-core

Tags: linux, centos, yum, xorg, wine

I've the following error on CentOS when installing wine:

```
sudo yum install wine
```

Error:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
wine-core-1.2.3-1.el4.rf.i386 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: /usr/X11R6/bin/xmessage is needed by package wine-core-1.2.3-1.el4.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: /usr/X11R6/bin/xmessage is needed by package wine-core-1.2.3-1.el4.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

xmessage is part of xorg-x11-apps (`sudo yum install xorg-x11-apps`):

```
$ rpm -ql xorg-x11-apps | grep xmessage
/usr/bin/xmessage
```

I've tried to make the symbolic link via:

```
cd /usr/X11R6/bin && sudo ln -s ../../../usr/bin/xmessage xmessage
```

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're installing a centos 4 package on what's most likely not a centos 4 machine. Get a version of the wine package that matches your OS.

And if your os is really centos 4: time to upgrade, centos 4 doesn't even get security patches anymore.

Comment: I've got CentOS release 5.8 (Final), my problem was that I had some rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el4.rf package installed. Removing it helped. Thanks for your point.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing several 3rd party repositories. You need to set up the yum priorities plugin. Especially, EPEL is known to cause conflicts with other 3rd party repos.

Please read and follow the instructions in:

http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities

Because you need wine, and wine is available from both rpmforge and EPEL, I suggest that you enable only one of them, not both.

To keep the repo status as simple as possible, use rpmforge OR EPEL as the only 3rd party repo for now. Remove or delete others. Then attempt to install wine.

The easiest solution is to [remove RPMforge](https://superuser.com/questions/412463/wrong-rpmforge-installed) by the following command (`check by rpm -qa | grep rpmforge`):

```
$ sudo rpm -e rpmforge-release
```

Comment: Yeah, rpmforge is to be avoided. It has some serious quality issues. I stick to CentOS+EPEL+homegrown packages

Comment: Or you could use the EL5 rpmforge release instead of the EL4 release.